# Deploying website on Vercel with Route53 subdomain

Tags: deployment, subdomain, amazon-route53, vercel

I am trying to deploy my Next.js web app on Vercel with Route53. But I am already using my root domain with main service which is `example.com`. 
I used to deploy with subdomin inside of  `example.com` hosted zone, which is `subdomain.example.com`.
But I had to add server, cdn, and other 2nd level subdomain like `server.subdomain.example.com`. So I created a new hosted zone for `subdomain.example.com` on Route53 and connected with root domain.
So I am trying to add `subdomin.example.com` on Vercel, but if I add this domain to Vercel project settings, they only get root domain current nameservers.
Is there anyway to add Route53 hosted zone domain to Vercel?